# Axios GET request fails with status code 500 when I recieve a single element (but not when I recieve many)

Tags: javascript, rest, get, axios

I'm learning Axios and I have bumped into a weird error while implementing some simple examples as practice.
I use a GET request to render articles stored in a DB. When I send more than one from the back-end it works just fine on the front-end, but not when I send only one.

I print in console the information retrieved from the DB before sending it in the response so I'm sure the request itself is made correctly and the information retrieved is what it should be. So the problem must be in the response, I guess.

I will try to provide all the relevant code.

### Back-end

Hibernate DAO

```
public ArrayList<Noticias> getNoticias(){
    ArrayList<Noticias> noticias = null;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        List l = session.createQuery("from Noticias").list();
        noticias = new ArrayList((List<Noticias>) l);
        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return noticias;
}

public Noticias getNoticia(String id) {
    Noticias n = null;
    try {
        session.beginTransaction();
        n = (Noticias) session.createQuery("from Noticias where id=" + id).getSingleResult();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }
    return n;
}
```

REST service

```
@Path("/noticias")
public class NoticiasREST {

  @GET
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response getNoticias() {
      DAONoticias dnoticias = new DAONoticias();
      ArrayList<Noticias> noticias = new ArrayList(dnoticias.getNoticias());
      noticias.forEach(noticia -> {
          System.out.println("Id: " + noticia.getId()
                              + " Autor: " + noticia.getUsuarios().getNombre()
                              + " Titulo: " + noticia.getTitulo()
                              + " Contenido: " + noticia.getTexto()
                              + " Fecha: " + noticia.getFecha());
      });
      return Response.ok(noticias).build();
  }

  @GET
  @Path("/{id}")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response getNoticia(@PathParam("id") String id) {
      DAONoticias dnoticias = new DAONoticias();
      Noticias noticia = new Noticias(dnoticias.getNoticia(id));
      System.out.println("Id: " + noticia.getId()
                          + " Autor: " + noticia.getUsuarios().getNombre()
                          + " Titulo: " + noticia.getTitulo()
                          + " Contenido: " + noticia.getTexto()
                          + " Fecha: " + noticia.getFecha());
      return Response.ok(noticia).build();
  }
}
```

### Front-end

JS (servicios.js)

```
function prueba3() {
  axios.get('rest/noticias/5')
  .then(function (response) {
      $.map(response.data, function(noticia) {
          $("main").append(genNoticia(noticia));
      });
  });
}

function prueba4() {
    axios.get('rest/noticias')
    .then(function (response) {
        $.map(response.data, function(noticia) {
            $("main").append(genNoticia(noticia));
        });
    });
}

function genNoticia(noticia) {
    return '<div class="noticia">' +
           '<p>Título: ' + noticia.titulo + '</p>' +
           '<p>ID: ' + noticia.id + '</p>' +
           '<p>Autor: ' + noticia.usuarios.nombre + '</p>' +
           '<p>Fecha: ' + formatFecha(new Date(noticia.fecha)) + '</p>' +
           '<p>Contenido: ' + noticia.texto + '</p>' +
           '</div>';
}
```

JSP

```
<html>
  <jsp:include page="head.jspf" />
  <jsp:include page="nav.jspf" />

  <main id="main">

    <script>prueba3();</script>
    <script>prueba4();</script>

  </main>

  <jsp:include page="footer.jspf" />

</html>
```

"prueba3" doesn't work while "prueba4" does. Remember that I print in console the information before sending the response so I know for sure that /rest/noticias/5 is retrieving correctly a single article (the correct one), with all its attributes.

"prueba3" produces the following error code in Chrome Developer Tools:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/ProyectoScansubs/rest/noticias/5 500 (Internal Server Error)
  (anonymous) @ spread.js:25
  e.exports @ spread.js:25
  e.exports @ spread.js:25
  Promise.then (async)
  r.request @ spread.js:25
  r.(anonymous function) @ spread.js:25
  (anonymous) @ index.js:20
  prueba3 @ servicios.js:68
  (anonymous) @ (index):35

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
  at e.exports (spread.js:25)
  at e.exports (spread.js:25)
  at XMLHttpRequest.l.(:8080/ProyectoScansubs/anonymous function) (https://unpkg.com/axios@0.18.0/dist/axios.min.js:8:3278)
```

I would greatly appreciate any input you could make on the subject as I'm quite lost on this one.

Thanks to everyone who took the time to read this even if you didn't or couldn't answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's your backend: `public Noticias getNoticia(String id) {` try opening the `rest/noticias/5` in your browser and see if there is any error information. Probably need to remove all the client side tags since this is a JAVA problem

Comment: The first thing you always do on a 500, is you go check the relevant server-side error logs.

Comment: @Cbroe you were right. There weren't any exceptions or errors on Glassfish log's but when I send an arraylist with just one element in the response it works correctly. For some reason Jackson serializes ArrayList<Noticias> correctly but not an element of class Noticias. Do you know why this may be?